# Any way to customize Paypal order summary to replace 'item' with 'service'?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

I have a client who has third-party shopping cart with Paypal implemented on his website. The client sells services (not products). When you add a service to a shopping cart and then get redirected to PayPal for payment and approval, the order summary looks something like this:

- Descriptions
- Full theory + practice driving course
- Item number: 3
- Item price: 500
- Quantity: 2

The client wants to replace `item` with `service`. When researching PayPal checkout page customization options, I have not found any way to control this in your hidden form inputs or curl options. All APIs seem to use the same identifier like `item_name` that translate to the same `item` in order summary. I wonder if there is any way to customize description to show 'service' instead of 'item'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there's no way to do this in Payments Standard. You could, at best, send the customer a separate receipt with the verbiage you want, but it will appear as `item` within the PayPal system.

Comment: yes, we already have customized customer emails but original PayPal receipts are required for taxation. You say it's not possible in Payments Standard; do you happen to know if is it possible with any other paypal payment solutions?

Comment: No. Those fields are common to all PayPal payments, even Payments Pro. The only place it might be different would be PayFlow but that's an entirely different system.

Answer (score 0):

@xsqox,

Instead of using a redirect, try placing the Payment page in a frame. This might allow you to replace "Item" with "service" using Jquery, or some other language.

Comment: this will not work for me; my client needs this change for taxation purposes as he needs to submit PayPal receipts to tax authorities. Because of this item thing, he has to do more paperwork.